# Power BI : Addcolumns and summarize

Tags: powerbi, summarize

I'm trying to get the number of vote records depending on the satisfaction of our customers. For example :

- 20 records voting for 5/10
- 10 records voting for 2/10
- 5  records voting for 9/10

This is a part of my dataset : 
[image]

I want to have for each `Opp title` , the number of records having `X` votes with `X` a scale from 1 to 10.

The `X` is the response of the customer for the `How likely would you recommend the experience you lived?` as shown in the dataset, in the last column.

I made a new table with this query where I added `Flag` to know if it's `POOR` , `MEDIUM` or `High`, but I'm not getting the requested result :

```
Summarize Table = 
ADDCOLUMNS (
    SUMMARIZE(
        NPS_18_7_2018;NPS_18_7_2018[Opp title];
        "Total order"; DISTINCTCOUNT ( NPS_18_7_2018[How likely would you recommend the experience you lived?])
    );
    "Flag"; IF ( [Total order] <= 5; "POOR"; IF ( [Total order] = 5; "Medium"; "High" ) )
)
```

I'm trying to generate a chart where I can find for the `VOTE = 5/10` for example , the number of `EP ID` who voted 5/10 for each `Opp title`.

One of the incorrect records I get as a result:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this would match your question more closely:

```
Summarize Table =
    SUMMARIZE(
        NPS_18_7_2018;
        NPS_18_7_2018[Opp title];
        NPS_18_7_2018[How likely would you recommend the experience you lived?];
        "Votes"; COUNT(NPS_18_7_2018[EP ID])
    )
```

This groups by title and rating and then count applies the count.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179850/discussion-between-amira-bedhiafi-and-alexis-olson).

Answer (score 0):

I realized that after the Power BI updates , I was looking for the Slicers.
I created a new slicer then select the data field to filter on :

- Opp title
- How likely would you recommend the experience you lived?
- ...

You can see documentation here : [Slicers in Power BI](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/power-bi/visuals/power-bi-visualization-slicers)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the name of the dataset which is Data and not NPS_18_7_2018

```
Summarize Table =
        SUMMARIZE(
            Data;
            Data[Opp title];
            Data[How likely would you recommend the experience you lived?];
            "Votes"; COUNT(Data[EP ID])
        )
```